# PHP - Apache can't write in a directory that just created

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, mkdir

I have a scripts that allows to assign files to products.  To avoid problems with name files repeating, each product has a specific directory.

The uplad directoy that contains all product-specific directories looks like this.

4 drwxrwx--x  3 pepe pepe  4096 Jan  9 17:08 . 
20 drwxrwxr-x 35 pepe pepe 20480 Jan  9 15:42 ..
 4 drwxrwxr-x  2 apache  apache   4096 Jan  9 17:08 001

Apache runs under user "apache" and "apache" is set as part of group "pepe".

If I try to upload a file to a product that doesn't have it's directory created the scripts create the directory (with the permissions shown for dir "001") and then tries to upload the file, but fails.

If I change the directory owner to pepe.pepe in SSH and then reupload the file it goes perfectly.

Why is apache creating a directory that in the next line of code can't write in?

How do I prevent to have to manually change ownership to the directory created, because my client obviously can't do it when assigning the files to all his products.

Comment: Are you sure apache is doing the writing? What language are your script files in?...

Comment: Try mkdir('path/to/dir',0700) That mode seems to work best for me. Oh and make sure the script creating the dir is owned by apache:apache and not pepe:pepe

Comment: @War10ck  The script is in PHP

Comment: @rwhite35 0770 allows the group to write. The scripts are all owned by pepe.pepe, but that should not affect the result given the group write permission, and if it did, shoudn't allow me to create the directory neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try chgrp() in your PHP to change the group to "pepe"? If it does not work, at least the errors would give you a hint. Another one comes from "safe mode":

> When safe mode is enabled, PHP checks whether the files or directories
>   being operated upon have the same UID (owner) as the script that is
>   being executed.

I would try changing (manually) the owning group of the parent dir(s) too to "apache".

Comment: That worked perfectly.. I had already tried chown() but returns a forbidden so I assume chgrp() will return the same but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

You should change permissions to the just created directory:

```
chmod('/path/to/directory', 0775);
```